# Inflection Points and derivatives

Tags: derivatives

Find all inflection points of the following Hill function:

$\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{Ax^3}{(a^3 + x^3)}$

assuming that $a > 0$.

How do I approach this question?

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x)=\frac{Ax^3}{a^3+x^3}=\frac{Aa^3+Ax^3-Aa^3}{a^3+x^3}=A-\frac{A a^3}{a^3+x^3}
$$
$$
f'(x)=-A a^3 \,\frac{-3x^2}{(a^3+x^3)^2}
$$
$$
f''(x)=-A a^3 \, \left( \frac{-6x}{(a^3+x^3)^2}-3x^2\frac{-6x^2}{(a^3+x^3)^3}\right)= \\
=-A a^3 \left( \frac{-6x(a^3+x^3)+6x 3x^3}{(a^3+x^3)^3}\right)=A a^3 \frac{6x(a^3-2x^3)}{(a^3+x^3)^3}
$$
Then the possible (in fact, they are) points of inflection are $x=0$ and $x=\frac{a}{2^{1/3}}$.

Comment: Why is there a -3 in front of the x^2? and why are you subtracting the equation from A in the first line?

Comment: i will edit to clarify it

Comment: Ready. There was a little mistake in the old calculation. I believe it is ok now.

Comment: Why is Aa^ 3 and not Ax^ 3? and also in the first line wouldn't +Aa^3 cancel out with -Aa^3 leaving us with Ax^3 as the numerator.

Comment: I add and substract $A a^3$ to simplify the expression.

Comment: I'm sure you can verify that the first line is ok. The right hand side is easier to derivate.